# Проблемы с запуском авторизационной activity VK на Android 7.0

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делал около года назад приложение на андроид. Приложение должно служить для просмотра видяшек со своей стены VK.

Задумка такая:  если пользователь авторизирован - стартовый экран сразу заполняется списком его видео. Если не авторизирован - то должно появиться окно авторизации.

Сейчас зашел снова в приложение и узрел странную картину. 
**Не корректно отображается окно авторизации пользователя.**

В окне авторизационной `activity` отсутствует заливка фона. Сквозь него видно фоновый главный экран. Стиль виджетов выглядит тоже как то некоректно.
Но все нужные поля для внесения логина и пароля работают.
Окно подтверждения разрешений и выхода такого же вида. Но функционал работает.

Это стартовая `activity` (пока без списка).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядит появившееся окно авторизации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В своем старом коде ничего не менял. Только повысил версию `gradle (с 4.1 до 4.6)` и `SdkVersion (с 25 до 28)`.

В `build.gradle` имплементировано `'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.9'`

В манифесте согласно инструкции указал:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity"
            android:label="ServiceActivity"
            android:theme="@style/VK.Transparent" />
```

Инициализация тоже по инструкции сделана:

```
public class Aplication extends android.app.Application {

    Context context;

    VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(VKAccessToken oldToken, VKAccessToken newToken) {
            if (newToken == null) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "AccessToken invalidated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        vkAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();
        VKSdk.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

Кастомных стилей не применял.

*В AndroidStudio:

targetSdkVersion 28

gradle-4.6*

***Апарат на котором запустил:***

Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X
Андроид: 7.0*

*Приложение "ВКонтакте" - не установлено.*

*Для доступа как и прежде используется VPN.*

Уже обрыл мануалы `VK` для разработчиков. На форуме `VK` ничего по этой проблеме не встретил.
Кастомизировать экран логина не получится, так как `VK` не дает это делать простым смертным.

В докумендации по `Andriod SDK` ничего не нашел кроме мистической фразы:

> ...в `<application>` стоит добавить
>
> ```
> <activity android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity" 
> android:label="ServiceActivity" 
> android:theme="@style/VK.Transparent" />
> ```
>
> иначе могут быть проблемы с запуском авторизационной activity.

Но у меня же все добавлено!

---

Относительно проверки на других устройствах.

Отображается коректно на реальных устройствах:
1) `Samsung Galaxi Win` **Android 4.1**. C экраном = `480x800`
2) `Xiaomi Redmi Note Pro 3 16GB` **Android 6.0**. C экраном = `1920x1080`.

То есть, отпадает вариант с пермишнами и вариант ошибки верстки для экрана  1920x1080. Так как у моего `Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X` экран тоже `1920x1080`.

---

В Logcat при запуске Своего приложения на Андроид 7.0 нашел такие строки:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
D/EgretLoader: The context is not activity
W/ContentCatcher: Failed to notify a WebView
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(143)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: vkNow is not defined", source: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6271282&scope=video,wall,friends,offline&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&v=5.21&response_type=token&revoke=1 (143)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(155)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'stickers' of undefined", source: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=6271282&scope=video,wall,friends,offline&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&v=5.21&response_type=token&revoke=1 (155)
```

---

Думал что я что-то криво сделал или что-то забыл.
Решил запустить [Официальный пример от ВК](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk).
Результат - активити логина на Андроид 7.0  выглядит так же не коректно.
А в логкате ВКшного приложения строки аналогичные моим:

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:100319497 intent:Intent { cmp=com.vk.vktestapp/com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity (has extras) }
D/EgretLoader: EgretLoader(Context context)
    The context is not activity
W/ContentCatcher: Failed to notify a WebView
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(143)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: vkNow is not defined", source: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3974615&scope=friends,wall,photos,nohttps,messages,docs,offline&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&v=5.21&response_type=token&revoke=1 (143)
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(155)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'stickers' of undefined", source: https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3974615&scope=friends,wall,photos,nohttps,messages,docs,offline&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=mobile&v=5.21&response_type=token&revoke=1 (155)
```

---

**UPD 12.11.2018:**

Для удобства решил не ковырять свое приложение, а продолжить поиски по поближе к оригинальному коду. Для ознакомления с проблемой сделал к себе [Fork официального приложения от ВК](https://github.com/vmarch/vk-android-sdk). Там сделал обновы в гредле.

А так же, собрал сразу [АПК и залил на гугл-диск](https://drive.google.com/open?id=155HQgweF94UAM3ThnoQsLRa203xNFBlq), что-бы можно было запустить тестовый образец который предлагает ВК без мороки с андроид студио. И, так сказать, увидеть воочию проблему.

Comment: Может, банально интернет глючит и CSS страницы просто случайно не скачался?

Comment: @andreymal та вроде как не зависит.  На старом моб загружает, на новом - нет. И там и там через VPN. Пробовал через вифи и через моб. Хотя, кое-что проверю...

Comment: Думал что пермишены не дал. Но вроде все нужные, даже с избытком даны. Хотя по документации ВК только интернет нужен. Но это же ВК, может какой то специфический еще нужен но его не написали.

Comment: @andreymal Нашел в логкат интересные строки. Правда как его пофиксить что-то ума не приложу(((

Comment: @woesss Можете подсказать что-то по этому вопросу?

Comment: Для чистоты эксперимента запустил тестовое приложение которое сваяли разработчики ВК - те же фаберже, только впрофиль.

Comment: @V.March, на старом и новом смартфоне разрешение и диагональ экрана одинаковые? Я это к тому, что может у вк вёрстка на твой экран поехала? Как вариант, создай эмулятор с твоими параметрами экрана от старого телефона и с версией ОС от нового телефона. Это чтоб исключить возможный косяк со стороны вёрстки вк, вдруг это на самом деле?

Comment: @zayn1991 та дело в том, что воспользоваться могу только реальными устройствами, на которые могу установить VPN.

Comment: @zayn1991 Экран видимо непричастен к этому багу. На таком же экране проверил как и у меня, но на версии андроид 6.0 - там все норм работает.

Comment: @andreymal Вы что-то говорили об ошибке загрузки CSS. Можете посмотреть ошибку которую я нашел в логкате?

Comment: @V.March она мне говорит лишь о том, что вместе с CSS просто не загрузился и JS тоже, так что увы

Comment: А ты запускал вообще приложение где-нибудь кроме своего телефона? У меня на эмуляторе с 24 api все нормально работает.

Comment: @yno7 На версии API 24 только со своего заходил. На версиях до 24 все норм отображается. Эмулятор не получится запустить. Уже писал что через впн захожу и только через браузер. А соответствующе у эмулятора нет доступа к этому каналу. Придется искать девайсы на апи 24 на стороне.

Comment: Я просто говорю тебе что проблема не в высоких версиях апи, а конкретно из-за особенности девайса. Попробуй обновить chrome и/или можешь еще попробовать в sdk подправить WebView вот так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367358/webview-on-android-7-0-doesnt-render-page

Comment: @yno7 Поищу такой же аппарат как и у меня. А ответ по ссылке пробовал - не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Докопался до истины - проблема оказалась с интернет доступом через ВПН.
Удалось проверить запуск экрана логина на том же телефоне, но уже без ВПН, а напрямую.

Как результат - окно логина загружается в нормальном виде. Верстка никуда не уезжает. И ошибки в логах нет.
Вывод - нужно доработку процесс синхронной загрузки данных с сервера вк.